# How to properly apply Function.apply.bind to Promise's resolution handler then()?

Tags: javascript, promise

EDIT: This approach is purely out of curiosity. Not a working solution neither I'm going to use elsewhere. Just trying to understand how THIS particular case works.

From this article:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md this suppose to work:

```
function spread(fn) {
    return Function.apply.bind( fn, null );
}

Promise.all(
    foo( 10, 20 )
)
.then(
    spread( function(x,y){
        console.log( x, y );    // 200 599
    } )
)
```

`foo()` is a function that returns an array of two Promises.
Here is my example, which doesn't work

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(55);
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(44);
});

Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(Function.apply.bind(
        function(x, y) {
            alert(x + ", " + y); // expecting popup with "55, 44"
        }, 
        null)
    );
);
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you must use `Function.apply` ? you can simply do `Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function( list ){ list.map() })`

Comment: No, of course not. I'm just trying to understand how it's suppose to work in this particular example.

Comment: Apparently you forgot the token `bind` in your code. I wonder how this didn't threw a syntax error.

Comment: My bad. Pasted an edited version. But doesn't work either way.

Comment: You still have a syntax error - one closing parenthesis too much. What exactly is ypur problem, don't you get any errors?

Comment: @Bergi you're right, my bad. Case solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the bind(), you have it omitted for some reason.

```
Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(Function.apply.bind(//correct
        function(x, y) {
            alert(x + ", " + y); // expecting popup with "55, 44"
        }, 
        null))
    );
);
```

This works by providing the apply function as the callback, with the following function bound as the thisArg.The second argument to the apply will be null. The thisArg will be called, basically what that means is that, the function provided will be called by apply, with no arguments. But then the "then" function comes into play calling the function, with it's own arguments, the last part is speculative.

```
function(x, y) {
    alert(x + ", " + y); // expecting popup with "55, 44"
}
```

Comment: This will not pop up "55,54" as Promise.all return an array !

Comment: @Anonymous0day: `Promise.all` returns *a promise for* an array.

Comment: @Bergi right ! i mean the argument to use in the next `then` will be an array.

Comment: @Anonymous0day: …and the bound `apply` function *does take* an array. There's nothing wrong with this (except for the superflous parenthesis).

Comment: @Bergi, one more time you are right ! i've focused on the wrong thing, thanks, and sorry for the noise !